# Suppressing Grails Plugin WARN messages for Deprecated Behavior

Tags: grails, logging, suppress-warnings

We use quite a few Grails plugins for our application and apparently some of them are still using the deprecated `ApplicationHolder.getApplication()`.  I can't seem to determine which ones are specifically and upgrading willy nilly is not an option.

When our log level is info or lower we get hundreds of these when grails starts up:

> WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [DEPRECATED] Method
>   ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed
>   in a future version of Grails.

Is there any way at all to suppress these?

Update:

Based on the answer from baiyubin, I was able to at least fold them in the console in IDEA.  However, that doesn't prevent 2095 lines from being added to my log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Grails 2.0 you can add a new VM parameter at startup:

```
-Dgrails.log.deprecated=false
```

Source: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8024?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to switch to eclipse/sts, there's a built in suppression option right next to each warning messages, where you can toggle whether suppress similar warnings

Comment: Not going to happen.  But thanks for letting me know.  Maybe IDEA has something similar.